# Array not being set in switch in my class

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I am setting up a search class for my site and I've run into something and I have no clue why it's not working.

Here is the class

```
<?php

class search
{
    public $location = array();
    public $keywords = array();

    /*
    construct method
    accepts $location and $keywords
    */
    public function __construct($location, $keywords='')
    {
        $this->location = $this->format_location($location);

    }

    /*method format_location
    accepts location value, determines its type... city, state, zip code
    returns array of properly formatted location values
    */
    public function format_location($input)
    {

        // check if location contains a zip code
        $zip_pattern = "/\d{5}/";
        $str = $input;
        preg_match($zip_pattern,$str,$regs);
        // if we do have a zip code lets put it in the location array
        (!empty($reg[0])) ? $this->location['zip'] = $reg[0] : '';

        // if we don't have a zip let's check for one of our pre=formatted locations, this will avoid unessesary regular expressions and database calls
        if(!$this->location['zip']) {

            $swinput = strtolower($input);
            switch($swinput) {
                case "chicago, il":
                echo 'hello';
                    $this->location[] = array('zip'   => 60601,
                                            'city'  => 'Chicago',
                                            'state' => 'IL',
                                            'lat'   => '41.8781136',
                                            'lon'   => '-87.629798',
                                            );
                                            break;
                case "naperville, il":
                    $this->location[] = array('zip'   => 60564,
                                            'city'  => 'Naperville',
                                            'state' => 'IL',
                                            'lat'   => '41.785863',
                                            'lon'   => '-88.147289',
                                            );
                                            break;
            }

        }

    }

}

?>
```

and then this is how I'm calling it

```
require("lib/search/class.search.php");
$lo = new search('chicago, il');
print_r($lo->location);
```

Problem is that nothing is getting set in the location property. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it causes your bug, but `if (!$this->location['zip'])` means `if ($this->location['zip'] == false)`. You want to know if the `zip` key is set, so use `if (isset($this->location['zip']))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use

```
/*
construct method
accepts $location and $keywords
*/
public function __construct($location, $keywords='')
{
    $this->format_location($location);

}
```

instead of

```
$this->location = $this->format_location($location);
```

Because format_location doesn't return anything.

Comment: Oh man I feel like a doof missing that. Thanks so much that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
preg_match($zip_pattern,$str,$regs);
// if we do have a zip code lets put it in the location array
(!empty($reg[0])) ? $this->location['zip'] = $reg[0] : '';
```

to

```
preg_match($zip_pattern,$str,$reg);
// if we do have a zip code lets put it in the location array
(!empty($reg[0])) ? $this->location['zip'] = $reg[0] : '';
```

?

Regards
Max

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match($zip_pattern,$str,$regs);
                                 ^---- S here

(!empty($reg[0])) ? $this->location['zip'] = $reg[0] : '';
            ^--no S                              ^-- no S
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try casting $swinput to a string when declaring the switch like:

```
switch((string)$swinput) {
```

If that doesn't work the problem may be in the conditions before getting to the switch failing. Are you seeing the 'hello' debugging message when you run this?